# How to add the store link and email and exit the application

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, ontap

How to add the store link and email and exit the application

[Click here to see the codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxN5h.png)

How to activate additions in the list

```
        drawer: const Drawer(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("More App"),
                  textColor: Colors.black,
                  iconColor: Colors.black,
                  leading: Icon(Icons.email),
                  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Contact Us"),
                  textColor: Colors.black,
                  iconColor: Colors.black,
                  leading: Icon(Icons.email),
                  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Log Out"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
                  textColor: Colors.black,
                  iconColor: Colors.black,
                  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                ),
              ],
            )),
```

thanks

i waiting <<<

i try but not done -

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some event when touching or clicking, you could use GestureDetector

Comment: Please detail ..

Comment: use some packages for example: [send emails](https://maneesha-erandi.medium.com/sending-emails-with-flutter-dd5e2c182fc)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).